# Is this possible?

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

I have a question, I'm using uploadify, and every time when a file finishes to upload, the script runs a code which is located in the **`onComplete`** statement, and the code from the  `onComplete` statement it's an ajax call to a page, let's call it X , how can I know when the script access the page X for the first time?

Comment: What needs to know the javascript or the php?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not familiar with uploadify, if you set a variable in the global scope (outside the onComplete), I'll call it var hasBeenCalled, set it to false at the page load.
When onComplete is called, do:

```
if (hasBeenCalled)
{
// not the first time
}
else
{
//first time
hasBeenCalled = true;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
var myFirstEvent = false;
var myFunOnComplete = function()
{
    if (!myFirstEvent)
    {
       // code for fist instance
    }

    // set finish the first instance
    myFirstEvent = true;

    // code for ajax call
    callAjax();

}


jQuery('#fInput').uploadify({
  ...
  'onComplete': myFunOnComplete,
  ...
});
```